# How to prove that $(Tz)(t)=\sin(t)+\int_{0}^{t} e^{-s^2}z(se^t)ds$ is contraction mapping.

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm having troubles proving that the map $(Tz)(t)=\sin(t)+\int_{0}^{t} e^{-s^2}z(se^t)ds$ is a contraction mapping for $t\in[0,\infty)$. Here $z$ is a continuous bounded function on $[0,\infty)$.

The metric space here is $M:=BC([0,\infty),\mathbb{R})$ with the metric $d_\infty(x,y)=\sup\limits_{t\in[0,\infty)}|x(t)-y(t)|$. I know this is a complete metric space with this metric.

$T:M\rightarrow M$ and I have already proven that $T(M)\subset M$

I know that $e^{-s^2}$ is bounded on $[0,\infty)$ and so $e^{-s^2}z(se^t)$ is bounded. But I think it doesn't help me to prove that

$\lvert(Tx)(t)-(Ty)(t)\rvert\leq C\lvert x(t)-y(t)\rvert$, for all $x,y \in BC([0,\infty),\mathbb{R})$ and $t\in[0,\infty)$

That is all the information I have about the problem.

Comment: Firstly, you should explicitly state your metric space, the domain and codomain of $T$.

Comment: @DannyPak-KeungChan Sorry. I already added all the information I have.

Comment: Does $BC([0,\infty),\mathbb{R}^{n})$ denote the set of all $\mathbb{R}^{n}$-valued
bounded continuous functions defined on $[0,\infty)$ ? If so, your
$T$ is ill-defined. For, $Tz$ should be a $\mathbb{R}^{n}$-valued
function defined on $[0,\infty)$. However, $\sin(t)$ is not an element
of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Comment: @DannyPak-KeungChan Sorry,  I changed it, It was a typo error. And yes, $BC([0,\infty),\mathbb{R})$ is the set of $\mathbb{R}$-valued bounded continuous functions definded on $[0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you actually need to prove is that "There exists a constant $0 \le C < 1$ such that $d(Tx,Ty) \le Cd(x,y)$ for all $x,y \in BC([0,\infty),\mathbb{R})$."

This is equivalent to showing that "There exists a constant $0 \le C < 1$ such that $|(Tx)(t)-(Ty)(t)| \le Cd(x,y)$ for all $t \in [0,\infty)$ and all $x,y \in BC([0,\infty),\mathbb{R})$."

Where you might be having difficulty is that the statement "There exists a constant $0 \le C < 1$ such that $|(Tx)(t)-(Ty)(t)| \le C|x(t)-y(t)|$ for all $t \in [0,\infty)$ and all $x,y \in BC([0,\infty),\mathbb{R})$." is actually a stronger statement than what you need to prove, since $|x(t)-y(t)|$ could be much smaller than $d(x,y)$ for some values of $t$.

To prove the statement that you need to prove, start by writing out what $|(Tx)(t)-(Ty)(t)|$ is and attempt to bound it in terms of $d(x,y)$.

\begin{align*}
|(Tx)(t)-(Ty)(t)| &= \left|\left(\sin t + \int_0^te^{-s^2}x(se^t)\,ds \right) - \left(\sin t + \int_0^te^{-s^2}y(se^t)\,ds \right)\right|
\\
&= \left|\int_0^te^{-s^2}x(se^t)\,ds - \int_0^te^{-s^2}y(se^t)\,ds \right|
\\
&= \left|\int_0^te^{-s^2}\left(x(se^t)-y(se^t)\right)\,ds\right|
\\
&\le \int_0^t\left|e^{-s^2}\left(x(se^t)-y(se^t)\right)\right|\,ds
\\
&= \int_0^te^{-s^2}\left|x(se^t)-y(se^t)\right|\,ds
\end{align*}

Can you continue from here?

Comment: In fact, I reach that point on the proof, but I don't know what else to do.

Comment: I need in the RHS $|x(t)-y(t)|$ but don't know how to get this term.

Comment: You don't need $|x(t)-y(t)|$ in the RHS. Note that $|x(\tau)-y(\tau)| \le d(x,y)$ for any number $\tau \in [0,\infty)$. In particular, that holds when $\tau = se^t$.

Comment: I'm such an idi*t.  Your are completely right, I was not seeing things that way.